# How to trigger the next iteration of a matrix if a condition is met - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, matrix, iteration

My for statements correctly iterate through the matrix as wanted (down the column then moving 1 to the right). I.e

---

```
1 2 3
4 0 6
7 8 9
```

---

will iterate `1,4,7,2,0,8,3,6,9`.
However, I need to skip the remaining downwards iteration if the value of the current iteration index is 0. I.e the above matrix should iterate `1,4,7,2,3,6,9`. So when we get to the value of 0 we skip the rest and start from the top of the next column looking right. I've played around with an if statement like

---

```
if(matrix[down][across]== 0){
                 across++;
                 down=0;
            }else{
```

---

But ran into understandable errors. Any ideas on how to produce this?

My code so far:

```
function solution(matrix) {
    let count = 0;
  
    for(let across=0; across<matrix[0].length; across++){
        for(let down=0; down<matrix.length; down++){
            
            
         
            console.log(matrix[down][across])
                 
            }
        }
    

   
 }
```

---

Comment: "The [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement."

Answer (score 1):

Using `break`, you can ask javascript to skip the next iterations of the current loop you are in. So, whenever you encounter a 0, you break out of the inner for loop and goes to the next iteration of the outer loop.

```
function solution(matrix) {
    let count = 0;
    for(let across=0; across<matrix[0].length; across++){
        for(let down=0; down<matrix.length; down++){
            if(matrix[down][across] == 0) {
                break;
            }
            console.log(matrix[down][across]);
        }
    }
 }
```